# ¿Como hacer INNER JOIN entre una tabla en SQL SERVER y un servidor vinculado?

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, tsql, postgresql-9.3

Bueno me explico, tengo una base de datos en *SQL SERVER* llamada *SIELAB* y otra base de datos en *PostgreSQL* llamada *reservas*, logré realizar la conexión correctamente y ya logré ejecutar una consulta *SELECT* desde un *stored procedure* en *SQL SERVER* a una tabla que tengo en *PostgreSQL*. La consulta la realicé de la siguiente manera:

```
SELECT * 
FROM OPENQUERY(MYLINKEDSERVER,
'SELECT usu_id_pk AS Id_usuario, usu_nombre_completo AS Nombre_usuario FROM reservas.usuario')
```

Ahora en mi *bd* de *SQL SERVER* tengo una tabla que tiene un campo *usu_id_pk* igual que en la tabla de la *bd* del servidor *PostgreSQL*, necesito hacer un *INNER JOIN* entre estas dos tablas para poder traer los datos que necesito de la tabla en *POSTGRESQL*.

Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias!

Comment: Espero te sirva https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine busca **Escribir una consulta que una tablas desde un servidor vinculado** seguro para todo caso es similar la operación; considera debe estar acceso a tabla no a StoreProcedure (aún cuando devuelva filas). Espero te sea de utilidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intente hacer el Join usando el servidor vinculado. Podría ser algo así:

```
SELECT
    t1.campo1
    ,...
FROM
    [BaseDatosLocal].[esquema1].[TablaLocal] t1
    INNER JOIN [LinkedServer].[BaseDatosRemota].[esquema2].[TablaRemota] t2 
ON
    t1.Id = t2.Id
```

Puede que el esquema2 no sea necesario incluirlo.

Espero sirva de algo.